# How to make data private and readonly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an comment input.

```
<div class="comment-input" contenteditable></div>
```

Inside the keydown event, I want to detect what is the type of new comment? There are 2 types in my example: New comment and replying comment.

My idea: add `comment-level` attribute to the div. Like these:

```
<div class="comment-input" data-comment-level="0" contenteditable></div>
```

or

```
$('.sub-comment [contenteditable]').data('comment-level', 1);
```

If `comment-level` is `0`, that's new comment. Otherwise, it's replying comment.

The problem: Both cases can be edited easily in client side. Pressing `F12` to edit the attribute in the `Elements` tab, or in the `Console` tab, try to enter:

```
// you are hacked
$('.sub-comment [contenteditable]').data('comment-level', 'foo');
```

My question: how to set/get data safely?

Comment: How do you determine if a comment is reply or new one?

Comment: you can set any custom property you want (note that it's just a property, not an attribute so it won't be shown in browser). The most commonly used custom property is known as prefixed with `data-`. And in jQuery you use `.data()` to get/set that custom property, not using `.attr()` which will surely be shown in the browser's inspector window.

Comment: when using `.data`, don't init your `data-` by adding that explicitly in the HTML tag. Use code instead.

Comment: @MaxZoom I do that based on `comment-level` attribute.

Comment: @KingKing Thank you! You make me think about `Symbol`, Is `.data(Symbol('custom-name'), 0)` better?

Comment: @foo I don't have any idea about what Symbol (meant by you) is here. But looks like it's a function .... Any way the point here is using `.data` and not init your `data-` attribute  ***in your HTML tag***. That would show the attribute. Just init it using script with `.data`. BTW I don't think you depend much on client-side environment, it's always not a safe environment. Anything important should always be checked/validated by the server. If the client is broken intentionally by user, your client app does not need to be in charge for that action.

Comment: even data stored using .data() can be inspected in dev tools, and manipulated...so nothing is ever completely private